# Uncaught fatal error from thread [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] shutting down ActorSystem

Tags: apache-spark, akka, spray

In my application, I am retriving data from cassandra and providing the rest api using akka spray. It is working fine when I am running through IDE. But when I am running through `Spark submit` locally on my machine got error as given below

> [ERROR] [04/05/2016 10:43:38.687] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [ActorSystem(default)] Uncaught fatal error from thread [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] shutting down ActorSystem [default]
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext$$anon$1.DDLStrategy()Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies$DDLStrategy$;
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext$$anon$1.(CassandraSQLContext.scala:89)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext.(CassandraSQLContext.scala:85)

My build.sbt as given below.

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.4.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.4.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" %  "1.4.0" withSources() withJavadoc()


resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/")

resolvers ++= Seq("Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Spray Repository"    at "http://repo.spray.io")


libraryDependencies +=
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.14"


libraryDependencies ++= {
  val sprayVersion      = "1.3.2"
  Seq(
    "io.spray"          %% "spray-can"       % sprayVersion,
    "io.spray"          %% "spray-routing"   % sprayVersion,
    "io.spray"          %% "spray-json"      % sprayVersion

  )
}
```

Please let me know what mistake I have done.Thanks in advance. All your suggestion are valueable.

Comment: For more information, it is raised when the path is routed and complete is called. Inside method,                                                                                 val cassandraContext = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)                                                here the issue came. Please let me know if you have any other doubts. Please let me know how to fix this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're probably submitting a JAR that contains only your code. You have to add spark-cassandra-connector to class path (for spark-submit) by using --jars parameter (see [Spark submit's advanced dependency management](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management))

Or, you can try building a fat JAR (which will include the dependency) and submit it as you're doing so far. You can build a fat JAR from SBT using [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am creating the JAR from SBT using sbt assembly. So it should not be a problem. Please let me know is there any other possibility.